# How to require predefined string values in python pydantic basemodels?

Tags: python, pydantic

Is there any in-built way in pydantic to specify options? For example, let's say I want a string value that must either have the value "foo" or "bar".

I know I can use regex validation to do this, but since I use pydantic with FastAPI, the users will only see the required input as a string, but when they enter something, it will give a validation error. All in-built validations of pydantic are displayed in the api interface, so would be great if there was something like

```
class Input(BaseModel):
     option: "foo" || "bar"
```

Answer (score 114, accepted):

Yes, you can either use an enum:

```py
class Choices(Enum):
    foo = 'foo'
    bar = 'bar'

class Input(BaseModel):
     option: Choices
```

see [here](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/api/standard_library_types/#enum)

Or you can use `Literal`:

```py
class Input(BaseModel):
     option: Literal['foo', 'bar']
```

see [here](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/api/standard_library_types/#typingliteral)

Comment: Thanks this worked. I also want to add that in python 3.8+ its `from typing import Literal`, while <3.8 you need to use `from typing_extensions import Literal`

Comment: Or for simplicity you can use `from pydantic.typing import Literal` which will work on both.

Answer (score 5):

Wanted to add another option here. You could also use a Regex. Worked better for me since Literal isn't available until python 3.8 (which is unfortunately not an easy upgrade for me) and since I'm only expecting a single string for each, enum didn't really fit.

```
class YourClass(pydantic.BaseModel):
  your_attribute: pydantic.constr(regex="^yourvalwith\.escapes\/abcd$")
```

Answer (score 4):

#### Easiest: Use `typing.Literal`

`Literal` is a good option when you can hardcode your values:

```py
class Input(BaseModel):
    option: Literal["foo", "bar"]
```

It will fail if your list of strings are dynamic:

```
allowed_values = ["foo", "bar"]

class Input(BaseModel):
    option: Literal[allowed_values]
```

#### Alt: Use Validator

Assuming it is not possible to transcode into regex (say you have objects, not only strings), you would then want to use a field validator:

```py
allowed_values = ["foo", "bar"]

class Input(BaseModel):
    option: str

    @field_validator("option")
    def validate_option(cls, v):
        assert v in allowed_values
        return v
```

#### Best: Reusable Field with Annotated Validator

Let's say this field (and validator) are going to be reused in your codebase. A better approach would be to create a "custom field type" with an [annotated validator](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/validators/#field-validators), as such:

```py
from typing import Annotated
from pydantic import BaseModel, AfterValidator


allowed_values = ["foo", "bar"]

def option_in_allowed_values(v):
    """Ensures option is allowed"""
    assert v in allowed_values
    return v

custom_option = Annotated[str, AfterValidator(option_in_allowed_values)]


class Input(BaseModel):
    option: custom_option
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to expand on Yaakov's answer.  You can use functools.partial to bake in your values list

```
from functools import partial
from typing import Annotated
from pydantic import BaseModel, AfterValidator


def allowed_values(v, values):
    assert v in values
    return v

class Input(BaseModel):
    option: Annotated[str, AfterValidator(partial(allowed_values, values=["a", "b"]))]
```