# FastAPI: How to specify possible values for a field in Pydantic's Basemodel?

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

I have a model like :

```py
# Imports
from pydantic import BaseModel

# Data Models
class MyModel(BaseModel):
    a: str
    b: str
    c: str

@app.post('/endpoint_to_post')
async def post_log(my_model: MyModel):
```

I want to specify some constraint on this model.
Indeed, I need a ***possible values*** constraint  on the field **C** of the model **MyModel**.

Like:

```py
# Imports
from pydantic import BaseModel

# Data Models
class MyModel(BaseModel):
    a: str
    b: str
    c: str in ['possible_value_1', 'possible_value_2']
```

Thank for your help :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to require predefined string values in python pydantic basemodels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61238502/how-to-require-predefined-string-values-in-python-pydantic-basemodels)

Comment: I didn't try it, but seems a good solution. Thank!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add drop down menu to Swagger UI autodocs based on BaseModel using FastAPI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74366289/how-to-add-drop-down-menu-to-swagger-ui-autodocs-based-on-basemodel-using-fastap)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use `Literal` https://peps.python.org/pep-0586/

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import Literal

# Data Models
class MyModel(BaseModel):
    a: str
    b: str
    c: Literal['possible_value_1', 'possible_value_2']
```

Comment: Is there can way where I can validate from a external list?

Answer (score 10):

You can use [enum](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/types/#enums-and-choices) from [Python stdlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html):

```
from enum import Enum
from pydantic import BaseModel


class CEnum(Enum):
    VALUE_1 = 'possible_value_1'
    VALUE_2 = 'possible_value_2'


# Data Models
class MyModel(BaseModel):
    a: str
    b: str
    c: CEnum
```

Pydantic will automatically convert any string matching the enum value to the correct enum instance and will raise `ValidationError` if it doesn't match anything. You can combine it with `Optional` or `Union` from Python's `typing` to either make this field optional or to allow other types as well (the first matching type from all types passed to `Union` will be used by Pydantic, so you can create a "catch-all" scenario using `Union[CEnum, str]`).

Comment: Thank for your answer :) 
I found another soltuion using pydantic.validator (and an unique model) if you want to check

Comment: This is much flexible.

Comment: This works but you will get an Enum after deserialization. If you *need it to be string* after deserialization, `Literal` is more appropriate as answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/74113892/14052910.

Comment: ConfigDict has a flag `use_enum_values = True` for this case https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/api/config/#pydantic.config.ConfigDict.use_enum_values

Answer (score 6):

I found a solution,

I used pydantic.validator to achieve this.

Example:

```py
# Imports
from pydantic import BaseModel, validator

# Data Models
class MyModel(BaseModel):
    a: str
    b: str
    c: str # in ['possible_value_1', 'possible_value_2']

    @validator('c')
    def c_match(cls, v):
        if not v in ['possible_value_1', 'possible_value_2']:
            raise ValueError('c must be in [possible_value_1, possible_value_2]')
        return v
```

cf https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/validators/