# How to add drop down menu to Swagger UI autodocs based on BaseModel using FastAPI?

Tags: python, swagger, fastapi, swagger-ui, openapi

I have this following class:

```
class Quiz(BaseModel):
    question: str
    subject: str
    choice: str = Query(choices=('eu', 'us', 'cn', 'ru'))
```

I can render the form bases on this class like this

```
@api.post("/postdata")
def post_data(form_data: Quiz = Depends()):
    return form_data
```

How can I display a drop down list for choice field ?

Comment: what is your frontend framework?

Comment: I am using OpenAPI (/docs)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Option 1

Use literal values. [`Literal`](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/types/#literal-type) type is a new feature of the Python standard library as of Python 3.8 (prior to Python 3.8, it requires the [typing-extensions](https://pypi.org/project/typing-extensions/) package) and is supported by Pydantic. Example:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Depends
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import Literal

app = FastAPI()
    
class Quiz(BaseModel):
    question: str
    subject: str
    choice: Literal['eu', 'us', 'cn', 'ru'] = 'us'

@app.post('/submit')
def post_data(data: Quiz = Depends()):
    return data
```

### Option 2

Use [`Enums`](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/types/#enums-and-choices) (also, see Python's [`enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html) module, as well as FastAPI's documentation on [Predefined values](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/path-params/#predefined-values)). By having your `Enum` sub-class inheriting from `str`, the API docs will be able to know that the values must be of type `string` and will be able to render correctly. Example:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Depends
from pydantic import BaseModel
from enum import Enum

app = FastAPI()

class Country(str, Enum):
    eu = 'eu'
    us = 'us'
    cn = 'cn'
    ru = 'ru'
    
class Quiz(BaseModel):
    question: str
    subject: str
    choice: Country = Country.us
    
@app.post('/submit')
def post_data(data: Quiz = Depends()):
    return data
```

Comment: but in this way, by using `data: Quiz = Depends()` all attributes turn into query parameters, and without `Depends()` they turn into a body without any drop-down menu in swagger. So is there any approach to having a body with a drop-down for the `choice` attribute?! or how can I have a query drop-down just for `choice` and a body for the rest attributes? I think I should have two pydantic schema, isn't it?