# How can I configure an enum list in FastAPI?

Tags: python, fastapi

I have a FastAPI endpoint that fetches all database records for an entity, applying a payload. One of the payload fields refers to the order when bringing the data (which can even be by more than one column). So I have this:

```
class PayloadExecution(BaseExecution):
    init_date__lte: Optional[datetime] = Field(None, alias="init_date_below_equal")
    final_date__gte: Optional[datetime] = Field(None, alias="final_date_above_equal")
    custom_order: Optional[List[OrderOptions]]

    class config:
        use_enum_values = True

class QueryPayloadExecution(PayloadExecution):
    @classmethod
    async def as_query(
        cls,
        init_date: Optional[datetime] = Query(None),
        final_date: Optional[datetime] = Query(None),
        tag: Optional[str] = Query(None),
        guid_execution: Optional[str] = Query(None),
        is_officialized: Optional[bool] = Query(None),
        worker_status: Optional[int] = Query(None),
        worker_info: Optional[str] = Query(None),
        official_name: Optional[str] = Query(None),
        status: Optional[int] = Query(None),
        last_real: Optional[datetime] = Query(None),
        subfamily_x_forecast_id: Optional[int] = Query(None),
        execution_type: Optional[str] = Query(None),
        init_date__lte: Optional[datetime] = Query(None),
        final_date__gte: Optional[datetime] = Query(None),
        custom_order: Optional[List[OrderOptions]] = Query(None),
    ):
        return cls(
            init_date=init_date,
            final_date=final_date,
            tag=tag,
            guid_execution=guid_execution,
            is_officialized=is_officialized,
            worker_status=worker_status,
            worker_info=worker_info,
            official_name=official_name,
            status=status,
            last_real=last_real,
            subfamily_x_forecast_id=subfamily_x_forecast_id,
            execution_type=execution_type,
            init_date__lte=init_date__lte,
            final_date__gte=final_date__gte,
            custom_order=custom_order,
        )

@router.get(
    "",
    response_class=JSONResponse,
    response_model=Optional[List[ExecutionInDB]],
    status_code=200,
    responses={
        200: {"description": "Execution found"},
        401: {"description": "unauthorized"},
    },
)
async def get_all(
    *,
    payload: QueryPayloadExecution = Depends(QueryPayloadExecution.as_query),
    skip: int = Query(0),
    limit: int = Query(99999)
):
    executions_responses = await execution_service.get_all_ordered(
        payload=payload.dict(exclude_none=True),
        skip=skip,
        limit=limit,
    )
    return executions_responses
```

As you can see, custom_order is a list of OrderOptions. So, this looks like this in my swagger:

[image]

But I don't want it to be generated like this, since the order in which they are sent is important. I would like it to appear as when it is simply a string:

[image]

(But I can select values from the enum). This way I can add them in the order I want. Is this possible? If it is, how is it done?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74370808/17865804) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75998823/17865804) answer your question?

Comment: Not entirely, because I get something like the first image. This is useful in the sense that it shows the available options, however it does not respect the order in this case _is_officialized will always come first and then -created_at), which is a problem for column ordering.

Comment: In the examples you cited, only one can be selected. In the code of the question I have it as List[OrderOptions] because I need to be able to select more than one. (In fact, I tried it and I can select more than one, but they are always sent in the order of the list shown in the swagger)